# libgdx: Other coordinatesystem when using textures

Tags: android, libgdx, touch, textures, coordinate-systems

I'm a little bit confused. I'm using libgdx for the first time and i have some problems with the coordinate systems. When i'm creating a texture and want to set the position, I do:

```
texture = new Texture("myGraphic.png", 0, 0);
```

and my picture will be positioned at the left bottom corner.

But when I try to get the touch position with:

```
 if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
    {
        Vector3 tmp = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),0);
        System.out.println("Coord:" + " + " + tmp.x + " + " + tmp.y);
    }
```

I recognized that (0,0) is in the left top corner. 
So I tried camera.unproject(tmp) before my output, but then i will get only values between -1 and 1. 
How do i get the same coordinate system for all elements?

Comment: show your code how you use camera ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Libgdx coordinate system for touch is `y-down` but for Screen or Image it's `y-up`.

Take a look of LibGDX [Coordinate systems](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems)

If can use camera, set y-axis pointing up by `camera.setToOrtho(false);` and get world point by `camera.unproject(vector3);` method.

```
public class TouchSystem extends ApplicationAdapter {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture texture;
    Vector3 vector3;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        batch=new SpriteBatch();
        texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        vector3=new Vector3();
        camera=new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false);   // this will set screen resolution as viewport
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texture,0,0);
        batch.end();

        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

            vector3.set(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),0);
            camera.unproject(vector3);
            System.out.println("Coord:" + " + " + vector3.x + " + " + vector3.y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        texture.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you very much. Another short question: Do I have to use the same camera from my MainGame Class or can I create a new camera in another classes (for example a new Screen)?

Comment: camera is not heavy object so you can create different camera on other screen.